# Appending a tag within a tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append a string that has multiple tags in it, however every time I try, it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" on the **3rd append only**, without that part, the code was working fine. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#columnas").on('input',function(){
        var cols = $("#columnas").val();
        var rows = $("#rows");
        rows.empty();
        for (i = 1; i <= cols; i++ ) {
            rows.append("<input class='linea-campo linea-titulo-ext"+i+"' name='linea-titulo-ext"+i+"' id='linea-titulo-ext"+i+"' type='text' class='form-control' required>");
            rows.append("<input class='linea-campo linea-id-ext"+i+"' name='linea-id-ext"+i+"' id='linea-id-ext"+i+"' type='text' class='form-control' required>");
            rows.append("<select class='linea-campo  linea-sql"+i+"' name='linea-sql"+i+"' id='linea-sql"+i+"'>
                    <option value='1'>INT</option>
                    <option value='2'>VARCHAR(MAX)</option>
                    <option value='3'>DATETIME</option>
                    <option value='4'>DECIMAL(10,2)</option>
                </select>");
            rows.append("<input class='linea-campo2 linea-f"+i+"' name='linea-f"+i+"' id='linea-f"+i+"' type='checkbox' class='form-control'>");
            rows.append("<input class='linea-campo2 linea-g"+i+"' name='linea-g"+i+"' id='linea-g"+i+"' type='checkbox' class='form-control'>");
            rows.append("<input class='linea-campo2 linea-b"+i+"' name='linea-b"+i+"' id='linea-b"+i+"' type='checkbox' class='form-control'>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can not have a line break in a string. (well you can, not like that.

Comment: Shouldn't it be <input .... />    ?

Comment: This is not related to the problem, but you have multiple `class=` attributes in your `input` elements. It probably won't cause a problem, but you could shorten/simplify your code by consolidating them, e.g. `'<input class="form-control linea-campo linea-titulo-ext" + i + "'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since its multiline you need to escape the line break with a backslash so your code for 3rd append should be like this

```
rows.append("<select class='linea-campo  linea-sql"+i+"' name='linea-sql"+i+"' id='linea-sql"+i+"'>\
<option value='1'>INT</option>\
<option value='2'>VARCHAR(MAX)</option>\
<option value='3'>DATETIME</option>\
<option value='4'>DECIMAL(10,2)</option>\
</select>");
```